# how use serach box in select type jqgrid when edit inline

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

15.1
i use select in jqGrid. i need to be able search into  select .
this demo: 
      https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/95/

```
colModel: [
    { name: "act", template: "actions" },
    { name: "id", width: 50 },
    { name: "PackageCode", width: 110 , editable: true },
    { name: "Name", width: 200, editable: true },
    { name: "d", width: 100, editable: true ,edittype: 'select',
      editoptions: { value: 'FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim;FE2:FedEx2;TN2:TNT2;IN2:Intim2'}
    },
],
```

I think use  `dataInit:function(el){}` jqGrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i want Able to search combox .This solution

```
   dataInit: function (domElem) {
            $(domElem).addClass("js-example-basic-single");
           $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
                                    }
```

[please see demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amir3164/dnfk8hmr/134/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you use `d:"FE"` in the input data and `editoptions: { value: 'FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim;FE2:FedEx2;TN2:TNT2;IN2:Intim2' }`. Then you probably want to display "FE" as `"FedEx"`. Thus you have to add `formatter: "select"`.

About the problem with searching. By default the filter toolbar use input element for all fields. If you need to use another type of searching then you should add `stype` and `searchoptions`, which described all searching properties

For example the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/dnfk8hmr/97/ uses

```
{
    name: "d", width: 100, editable: true,
    formatter: "select",
    edittype: 'select',
    editoptions: {
        value: 'FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim;FE2:FedEx2;TN2:TNT2;IN2:Intim2'
    },
    stype: 'select',
    searchoptions: {
        sopt: ["eq", "ne"],
        noFilterText: "Any"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks dont use filter .i want serach in select when edit i want Similar jQuery Chosen

Comment: @saeed3164: Your original demo do use `filterToolbar`, but uses `edittype: 'select'` only for editing. You can add `navGrid` call to allow the user to use Searching Dialog too. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/dnfk8hmr/99/. The usage of different plugins like select2 or Chosen is **absolutely new question**. The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yvbt6w54/ from [README 4.14.0](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README4.14.0.md) and https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/su7ebs65/ from README 4.14.1 demonstrates the usage of select2, jQuery Autocomplete and `<datalist>`

Comment: thanks im add  dataInit: function (domElem) {             $(domElem).addClass("js-example-basic-single");   } to demo https://jsfiddle.net/amir3164/dnfk8hmr/124/ i want select  when button edit show search select